# Fill with color the shape points in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the data below

```
ww<-dput(ww)
structure(list(`Average Wt` = c("OVX", "SHAM", "Cycling"), `9` = c(19.6166666666667, 
18.9666666666667, 19.4225), `10` = c(21.5916666666667, 19.2916666666667, 
19.7025), `11` = c(22.2666666666667, 19.3666666666667, 19.7225
), `12` = c(22.25, 19.2166666666667, 19.5775), `13` = c(22.4, 
19.8583333333333, 20.1275), `14` = c(23.2, 19.8083333333333, 
20.1325), `15` = c(23.6166666666667, 20.525, 20.29), `16` = c(24.6166666666667, 
21.3416666666667, 21.065), `17` = c(26.3583333333333, 21.5333333333333, 
21.5325), `18` = c(27.025, 21.5583333333333, 21.4375), `19` = c(27.9833333333333, 
21.8666666666667, 21.63), `20` = c(28.7916666666667, 22.0916666666667, 
21.6175), `21` = c(28.975, 22.0416666666667, 21.875)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

and with

```
# Reshape the data to long format
ww_long <- ww %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -`Average Wt`, names_to = "Weeks", values_to = "Weights")

# Define shapes for different groups
shapes <- c("OVX" = 0, "SHAM" = 2, "Cycling" = 1)



# Plotting
ggplot(ww_long, aes(x = as.numeric(Weeks), y = Weights, group = `Average Wt`, shape = `Average Wt`, color = `Average Wt`)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1.5) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Weights - sd(Weights), ymax = Weights + sd(Weights)), width = 0.2, size = 1) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = shapes) +
  labs(title = "Weekly Weights", x = "Age (Weeks)", y = "Weights (g)", color = "Group", shape = "Group") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = as.numeric(names(ww)[-1]), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(16, 32, by = 2), expand = c(0, 0), labels = function(x) round(x)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(16, 32)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey90"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "white"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(color = "black"),
        axis.text = element_text(color = "black"),
        axis.ticks = element_line(color = "black"),
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),  # Bold axis titles
        legend.position = "right",
        plot.title = element_text(face = 'bold', hjust = 0.5))
```

I create
[image]

how can I make these shape points to be filled with color and not just be empty?

Comment: Try changing the `shapes` object to `shapes <- c("OVX" = 22, "SHAM" = 24, "Cycling" = 21)` And adding `fill = `Average Wt` to the call to `aes`; remove `scale_shape_manual(values = shapes)`

Comment: Use a [filled shape](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html).  And remember that `colour` controls the colour of the outline of the shape, `fill` controls its interior colour.  So add `aes(fill = \`Average Wt\`)` to your `geom_point()` call.